# Como importar mixins em single file components?

Tags: vue.js, vue.js-2

Ao tentar importar o mixin ocorre o seguinte problema

> Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'components' of undefined"

Porém não tem nada de anormal nos components pois ao tirar o mixin tudo funciona normalmente.

**metodos/metodo_Div.js**

```
export default {
  methods : {
        inserirDiv (event) {
            let componente = new flexdiv().$mount();
            this.$refs.filhosDoElemento.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', componente.$el );
        },  
    }
}
```

**./App.vue**

```
import { methodDiv } from './metodos/metodo_Div'
...
mixins : [methodDiv],
...
```

obs. estou usando browserify.

Comment: No teu código não vejo `components` em lado nenhum. Podes mostrar a linha que tem isso?

Comment: @Sergio, já arrumei, obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrumei da seguinte forma

**metodos/metodo_Div.js**

```
export const metodoDiv = {
  methods : {
        inserirDiv (event) {
            let componente = new flexdiv().$mount();
            this.$refs.filhosDoElemento.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', componente.$el );
        },  
    }
}
```

**./App.vue**

```
import { metodoDiv } from './metodos/metodo_Div'
...
mixins : [metodoDiv],
...
```

Lembrando que o nome da variável instanciada no import tem de ser igual a const definida no mixin.

Answer (score 1):

Vc pode simplismente remover o as {}, não seria suficiente? Creio que o componente iria funcionar. Ficaria

```
import metodoDiv from './metodos/metodo_Div'
...
mixins : [metodoDiv],
...
```

Comment: cara tentei tirar aqui e não funcionou, acho que é algum tipo de convenção pois não se trata da importação de um componente e sim de um simples mixin, o {  } ajuda a organizar melhor também.